# Docker-machine: download packages in image: Err:1 failure resolving

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-machine

I have created a docker machine behind my proxy. First I couldn't pull images. I've recreated the machine with:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
    --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://xx:8080/ \
    --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://xx:8080/ \
    docker-machine
```

Now I'm able to pull images, start containers, but the problem is when I try to create my own images using a Dockerfile:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get -y update
```

Error:

```
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Running in 31050162ef49
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

My proxy settings are set. I also tried to put them in my Dockerfile but it keeps failing. What is wrong?

Comment: What is your dns resolved to?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the proxy settings as arguments to the build command:

```
docker build --build-arg http_proxy="http://xx:8080/" --build-arg https_proxy="http://xx:8080/" ...
```

In general, I would recommend installing a tool to transparently route all traffic from the machine to the http proxy. This will remove all the pain for configuring all tools to run behind proxy.

For Linux you can use [Redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/). There are also docker images on Dockerhub to install it :) .

For Windows or MAC you can use [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/).